# Why does my Pandas DataFrame contain an empty column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Rather, why does it output an empty first column to csv when I call `to_csv`. I'm not certain if the dataframe actually contains an extra column or merely outputs one to csv. I have the code below, and when I open its output, `times.csv`, I get an "empty" first column:

```
,Start,End
0,2020-05-23 20:27:39.388228,2020-05-23 20:27:43.24543

import cv2, time, pandas
from datetime import datetime

first_frame=None
status_list=[]
times=[]
df=pandas.DataFrame(columns=["Start","End"])

video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:    
    check, frame = video.read()
    status=0
    grey=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grey=cv2.GaussianBlur(grey,(21,21),0)

    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame=grey
        continue

    delta_frame=cv2.absdiff(first_frame, grey)
    thresh_frame=cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh_frame=cv2.dilate(thresh_frame, None, iterations=2)

    (cnts,_)=cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for contour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour)<10000:
            continue
        status=1
        (x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 3)

    status_list.append(status)    
    if len(status_list)>=2:
        if status_list[-1]==1 and status_list[-2]==0:
            times.append(datetime.now())
        if len(status_list)>=2 and status_list[-1]==0 and status_list[-2]==1:
            times.append(datetime.now())

    cv2.imshow("Capturing", grey)
    cv2.imshow("Delta", delta_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Threshold", thresh_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Colour Frame", frame)

    key=cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key==ord('q'):
        if status==1:
            times.append(datetime.now())
        break

print(status_list)
print(times)

for i in range(0,len(times),2):
    df=df.append({"Start":times[i],"End":times[i+1]},ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv(r"MotionDetector\times.csv") 

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I suspect this has something to do with the dataframe's indexing, but I haven't specified anywhere that I want more than a simple two-column grid.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `df.head()` before you call `df.to_csv()`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional column you see is the index of the dataframe (the first line in the csv is empty here as your index has no name). You can switch it off in the output by `index=False`:

```
df.to_csv(r"MotionDetector\times.csv", index=False)
```

(there's always an index in the dataframe; when you use `ignore_index=True` in the `append` it just means that the index (if any) of the data to append will be ignored and a new index will be created, see the [example in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html))